# No Internet on Diskless Client - Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: boot, internet, nfs, pxe

So I have been working with PXE booting a diskless client using.

My setup includes TFTP, dnsmasq and an NFS share.

Using TFTP and dnsmasq I can do PXE booting. I prepared an OS and copied the rootfs to a remote location or an NFS server.

Everything works and my NUC / PC boots over PXE and also mounts the remote rootfs at /. The only problem I am having is I cannot access the internet when using this setup but the internet does work when I boot from the NUC's hard drive which has the same OS and the same cables connected (ethernet).

Why is the internet not working when I PXE boot the diskless client ? I need some advice troubleshooting this.

I am newbie so feel free to ask me for relevant outputs that would help to get to bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the Dnsmasq was hosting its own gateway. So every time I tried to connect to internet it was going through my Dnsmasq VM (which was kind kind of setup to be its own intranet).

The solution was to add the following lines in dnsmasq.conf to diable the gateway or any DNS hosting :-

#disabling the default router (gateway)

dhcp-option=3

#disabeling the DNS

dhcp-option=6